NextJS Turbo monorepo deployment issue on AWS Amplify
I am deploying nextjs turbo monorepo on AWS Amplify. AWS amplify is not giving me any errors but it is neither showing anything. Instead it is showing "Internal Server Error".
While creating the project, I check marked that my project is a monorepo but currently I am only deploying the client app.
I have deployed to the vercel but that is working fine. On vercel I created 2 projects and deployed admin and client separately. I only configured build command and vercel managed everything else.
These are vercel build commands for both apps
cd ../.. && npx turbo run build --filter=client
cd ../.. && npx turbo run build --filter=admin
amplify.yml
version: 1
applications:
  - appRoot: apps/client
    frontend:
      phases:
        preBuild:
          commands:
            - cd apps/client
            - npm i pnpm --global
            - npx pnpm install
        build:
          commands:
            - cd ../.. && npx turbo run build --filter=client
      artifacts:
        baseDirectory: apps/client/.next
        files:
          - '**/*'
      cache:
        paths:
          - .next/cache/**/*
          - .npm/**/*
      buildPath: /

Environment Variables
All branches    AMPLIFY_DIFF_DEPLOY         false
All branches    AMPLIFY_MONOREPO_APP_ROOT   apps/client

Mono Repo Folder Structure:

I tried deploying options (i.e. marking project as monorepo and unmarking project as monorepo). But no solutions worked.
